# Task never defined: default, To list available tasks, try running: gulp --tasks

Tags: node.js, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-sass

When running the following code I receive the following error:

```
[23:00:29] Task never defined: default
[23:00:29] To list available tasks, try running: gulp --tasks

gulp -v
CLI version: 2.2.0
Local version: 4.0.1
```

Can you let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

//compile scss into css
function style() {
  //1. where is my sass file going to be
  return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.sass')
  //2. pass that file through sass compiler
  .pipe(sass())
  //3.Where do I save the compiled css
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
}


exports.style = style;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the error says, you aren't defining a `default` task.

Either

- run `gulp style`, or
- export `style` as `default` (`exports.default = style`)